# JsDoc doubles my classes

Tags: jsdoc

I am using John Resig's [Class extend](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) to build a set of components, and I am using JsDoc to create the documentation for them. When I create a "class" like this:

```
/**
 * Tests a thing to see what it is, baby
 * @param {string=}Id the Id babyyyy
 * @constructor
 */
TestThing = function(Id){
    /**
     * The thing's id
     * @type {string=}
     */
    this.Id = Id;
}

/**
 * Gets the thing
 * @param {number} id
 * @returns {number}
 * @memberof TestThing
 */
TestThing.prototype.Get = function(id){
    return 5;
}
```

JsDoc works as expected, creates a class in the documentation.

When I create one using John's extend:

```
/**
 * Tests a thing to see what it is, baby
 * @constructor
  */
 TestThing2 = Class.extend({

     /**
      * Creates another thing
      * @constructs TestThing2
      * @param {number} id
      */
     init: function(id) {
         /**
          * The thing's id
          * @type {string=}
          */
         this.Id = id;
     },

     /**
      * Gets the thing
      * @param {number} id
      * @returns {number}
      * @memberof TestThing2
      */
     Get: function(id) {
         return 5
     }
 })
```

I get documentation with 2 versions of the class on the same page, the first one without the constructor arguments (so *new TestThing2()*) and the second with the arguments (*new TestThing2(id)*).

Obviously I don't want two versions of documentation, especially when the first is "wrong". I'm guessing I'm missing some tag or something, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason dropping the first doclet in your second example would be unacceptable? If I drop it, I get something that looks okay to me.

Comment: @Louis, that seems to be the solution. I guess I was mashing together different examples I was trying to follow. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll put in an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the first doclet in your second example, you'll get only one class in the documentation, with links and docs pointing to the right place.